# Fill a C++ array with numbers according to a pattern

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I have a pattern in which I want to fill an array:

> even indices value = -1

> odd indices value = 1

I currently achieve it like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int generator(){
    static int i = 1;
    i *= -1;
    return i;
}

std::array<int ,64> arr;
std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), generator);
```

Edit: Current implementation has a caveat - returned value of `generator` doesn't depend on iteration's object index.

Is there a way to pass current index to the `generator` function so it's output will depend on this index?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pass current index" to `generator`? This code already appears to do what you want (except that you have 1 at odd indices and -1 at even). Are you just asking how to write `generator` as a lambda?

Comment: @cigien: I think his point is that, if you call it a second time, it will potentially fail due to the static variable not being re-initialized. So he wants one that can be called multiple times.

Comment: You seem to be asking about how to declare the function with a parameter. But why? Your code works, doesn't it? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates that problem.

Comment: @joepol please edit the question and add your additional concern. I believe Nicol Bolas is  correct.

Comment: A one-liner: `std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [v = -1]() mutable { return v = -v; });`

Answer (score 6):

Your `generator` function has a `static` local variable, which preserves its state across every call. This means that if you use `generator` in a *different* call it remembers its old state, which might not be what you want.

You can fix this by writing a function that gives you a "generator" every time you call it. Note that the returned value (i.e. the generator itself) is just a `mutable` lambda, so that the value of `i` is preserved across multiple calls to that lambda.

```
auto gen() 
{
    return [i = -1]() mutable 
    { 
       i *= -1; 
       return i; 
    };
}

// usage ...

std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), gen());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ha8f98).

Answer (score 3):

As @cigen has pointed out, your code works as written.

But to try to answer your question, "Is there a way to pass current index to the generator function?" - the answer is "no, not with `std::generate`". Here's a sample implementation of that call (taken from [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *first++ = g();
    }
}
```

Points to note:

- This implementation of `generate` does not use indexes, so it can't pass them to the generator.
- The generator function is nullary (it takes no parameters), so generate can't pass the index, even if it had it.

Answer (score 2):

All of the solutions assume your generator will be called sequentially, what about parallel and out-of-sequence execution?

```
std::array<int, 64> arr;
std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr.begin(), [](auto const i){return i % 2: -1 : 1;});
```

You want to use the wrong function. If the element index is an argument to your generator, then `std::transform()` fits your requirements better.

EDIT:
You need c++20 for an authoritative solution:

```
  std::array<int, 64> arr;
  auto const g(std::views::iota(decltype(arr)::size_type{}, arr.size()));
  std::transform(g.begin(), g.end(), arr.begin(), [](auto const i){return i % 2 ? -1 : 1;});
```

or:

```
  std::array<int, 64> arr;
  std::ranges::copy(std::views::iota(decltype(arr)::size_type{}, arr.size()) | std::views::transform([](auto const i){return i % 2 ? -1 : 1;}), arr.begin());
```

You can run this in parallel and/or out-of-sequence and there may be other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach state to a function it is better to use a function object rather than function local static variables (for the very reason you discovered: reusability).

```
struct generator2 {
    bool even = true;
    int operator()(){
        even = !even;
        return even ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::array<int ,64> arr;
    std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), generator2{});
    for (auto e : arr) std::cout << e;
}
```

What is passed to `std::generate` here is an instance of type `generator2` whose `operator()` will be called.

> Is there a way to pass current index to the generator function?

No. The generator for [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) must be callable without parameter:

> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> Ret fun();
> ```
>
> The type Ret must be such that an object of type ForwardIt can be
> dereferenced and assigned a value of type Ret. ​

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's hard to do with `std::generate` doesn't mean it can't be done. You can write your own version of `generate`:

```
namespace mystl {
  template<class ForwardIt, class Generator>
  void generate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g)
  {
    int idx = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        *first++ = g(idx++);
    }
  }
}
```

Don't be limited by the standard algorithms; there's nothing magical about most of the ones in the standard library. Don't be afraid to write your own!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass current index to the `generator` *function* with `std::generate`.
But you can use a *lambda* to do that:

```cpp
std::array<int ,64> arr;
auto generator = [i = 1, n = 0] () mutable {
    // n is the current index here
    i = -i;
    n++;
    return i;
};
std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), generator);
```